# Intergrating Static Site generators with php

Tags: php, jekyll, wintersmith

I'm currently building a website using php that won't need regular updating and I thought of using static site generators as it will have a blog like feature. However my website contains a form the will link with a database and the problem i'm having is that the static site generators don't recognize and parse php.

I am currently considering using one of three static site generators
 -Jekyll
 -wintersmith
 - Piecrust

I was wondering if this can be done or are static site generators just for static pages

Comment: You can also look at my static site generator which uses vanilla PHP and generates HTML files and deploys to GitHub pages https://github.com/atas/ssg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Jekyll, you can use the `{% raw %}` tag to avoid processing a specific part of your files. For example:

```
This will be {% raw %}<?php echo("parsed"); ?>{% endraw %} correctly.
```

After processing, the above should be translated to `This will be <?php echo("parsed"); ?> correctly.`

Answer (score 6):

If you are hosting Jekyll generated website into a regular web server with php, you might need to generate index.php instead of index.html.

To do so, you can define permalink in that exact page in the front matter area:

```
---
layout: default
title: Some page title
permalink: somelink/index.php
---
```